# How can I read information from a specific cell in a closed workbook then paste it in a cell in my active worksheet using VBA in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if anyone knew how one can reference a cell from a closed workbook using VBA.

I know how to reference a range of cells using ADO and SQL but I don't know how to create a SQL query for a specific cell.

While browsing the internet i came across some code that uses "ExecuteExcel4Macro" but I am unable to find any real documentation for this function/command. In fact the documentation on the MSDN website regarding this command is rubbish and vague and quit frankly not helpful at all.

Anyway I digress; Ideally, I would like to call on a cell from an external workbook without having to open said workbook. The code I am trying to get to work is as follows:

```
    Sub update_overview() 

Dim wbPath As String 
Dim wbName As String 
Dim wsName As String 
Dim cellRef As String 
Dim data As Variant 

wbPath = "C:\examplepath\" 
wbName = "Core (N)i.xls" 
wsName = "Sheet1" 
cellRef = "C5" 

'data = GetData(wbPath, wbName, wsName, cellRef) 

ThisWorkbook.Activate 
Sheets("Overview").Select 
With Selection 
ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Clear 
ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Select 
ActiveCell = GetData(wbPath, wbName, wsName, cellRef) 
End With 


End Sub 


Private Function GetData(ByVal wbPath As String, _ 
wbName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant 

Dim arg As String 

GetData = "" 
arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _ 
wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1) 

GetData = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg) 
End Function
```

When i run the macro the only thing it returns is #REF

I have also tried:

```
Sub Sample() 
Dim wbPath As String, wbName As String 
Dim wsName As String, cellRef As String 
Dim Ret As String 

'wbPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\" 
wbPath = "C:\Users\my.name\Desktop\" 

wbName = "QOS DGL stuff.xls" 
wsName = "ACL" 
cellRef = "C3" 

Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _ 
wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150) 

MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret) 
End Sub
```

When the code reaches MsgBox I get a type missmatch error. If i get rid of the msgbox command and try to continue to paste to the cell with

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate 
Sheets("Overview").Select 
With Selection 
ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Clear 
ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Select 
ActiveCell = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)
```

I still get the #REF! error

Can anyone tell me: 
1) is this the best technique to be using? 
2) What is wrong with my code? and, 
3) Is there a better way to reference a single cell from an external workbook using ADO or DOA or a technique i am unaware of.

Also does anyone know of any extensive documentation on how to use the ExecuteExcel4Macro function.

Please help; Thanks

FYI I am on excel 2003

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259862/executeexcel4macro-to-get-value-from-closed-workbook/9261915#9261915

Comment: this sounds a lot like an issue I had take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535789/vba-close-workbook-after-acquiring-necessary-information/39536483?noredirect=1#comment66390620_39536483

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

`arg = "='" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & cellRef`

```
Sub Test()

Dim wbName As String
Dim wbPath As String
Dim wsName As String
Dim cellRef As String
Dim calcState As Long

calcState = Application.Calculation

wbPath = "C:\users\david_zemens\"
wbName = "a report.xlsx"
wsName = "Sheet1"
cellRef = Range("B2").Address

Dim arg As String
arg = "='" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & cellRef 'Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveCell.Value = arg
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value 'essentially a paste/values over the formula.
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = calcState



End Sub
```

Comment: +1 from me and questions: are there any reason for setting `.Calculation` and `.DisplayAlerts` in your Sub? In which situation do you consider them necessary??

Comment: `DisplayAlerts=False` suppresses an "update links" dialog that I was getting when writing an external reference to the `cell.value`.  The `Calculation` setting may not do anything at this point, I may have inadvertently left that in as previous attempt to suppress the update links dialog.