# VBA - Close workbook after acquiring necessary information

Tags: vba, excel

Your assistance is required on solving this world (Excel VBA) problem.
I am using a VBA to populate an immense workbook (500 Cells per row), from a bucket load of workbooks(Qty=96).
The VBA I am using got created by [@Kevin][1] and it works for about 20 files until my pc runs out of memory and crashes Excel.
This kind of works great for working with such an immense amount of cells per workbook, because opening and closing each workbook adds up to the process quite a lot. Opening each work book and copy all 500 cells and close, then proceed with the next one and so on x ±96 times, but that would be more complicated than just making this one work, if you have any of the 2 solutions please help!

Here is the VBA I am using:

```
Function GetField(Path As String, WorksheetName As String, CellRange As String) As Variant

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set wb = GetObject(Path)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
Set rng = ws.Range(CellRange)

GetField = rng.Value

wb.close 

End Function
```

Comment: You're trying to use a `Function`, but have `Application.Quit` in there. I'm not sure if you can do that.  Instead, turn it into a `Sub` (you'll have to create variables for those that are being passed through) and see if that works.

Comment: you never tell it what workbook to close.

Comment: @DougCoats, I also Tried wb.Close
Where  wb = GetObject(Path) or
GetObject(Path).Close SaveChanges:=True

Comment: FWIW, this is utterly wrong: a worksheet function should be `input -> processing -> output`, **without any side-effects**. That's why a UDF cannot alter other cells' contents. A worksheet function that closes a workbook whenever it calculates sounds like a recipe for disaster, sooner or later.

Comment: @BruceWayne, That is how desperate I am. I am trying just about anything I find on the web, I will give your recommendation a try and post any progress, Thank you!

Comment: @Mat'sMug, I is Currently a Disaster, would you recommend any alternatives to the current situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

To answer your original question, you have to activate the workbook first, then close the active workbook. **However, doing this in a function is very poor practice and will more than likely perform in non-intuitive ways.**

The following is the fix to your original code:

```
Function GetField(Path As String, WorksheetName As String, CellRange As String) As Variant

    'code

    wb.Activate 'Activate the opened workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close 'Close the active workbook

End Function
```

**Performing the `.Close` inside your function is not advised.**

Instead, to achieve the same thing without worry, make a `Sub` to close the workbooks that are opened by your function. We can achieve this by doing the following:

```
Sub closeWB(Path As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = GetObject(Path)
    wb.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

And then call on it from the same place you're calling your function. Just place it after the function call..

```
Sub YourMainSub()
    Path = "C:\Users\you\Desktop\file example.xlsm"
    something.GetField(Path, "Sheet 1", "A1")
    Call closeWB(Path)
End Sub
```

**After a lot of discussion between Allan and I, we discovered a solution to his problem. Ultimately using a UDF on the worksheet wasn't meeting his needs. As such we changed directions and made a routine that essentially did the same thing, but without having worksheet functions. This not only reduced the file size, but also made importing the data and setting up for the data import significantly faster. Below is a sample excerpt, in case anyone with this same issue wants a second option that may perform better.**

I could have put the data importing (Where we `Call DataLoop()`) in it's own For loop, but chose not to because maintaining a simple easy to edit code was more important than visual efficiency.

```
'The function that imports the data
Public Function GetField(Path, file, WorksheetName, CellRange) As Variant
   Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, field As String

   If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"

   If Dir(Path & file) = "" Then
       GetField = "File Not Found"
       Exit Function
   End If

   field = "'" & Path & "[" & file & "]" & WorksheetName & "'!" & Range(CellRange).Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
   GetField = ExecuteExcel4Macro(field)
End Function

'A loop that calls on the function
Sub DataLoop(DataRange As Range, SourceRow As Long, SourceColumn As Integer, Path, file, WorksheetName)
    Dim rcell

    For Each rcell In DataRange
        rcell.Value = GetField(Path, file, WorksheetName, Cells(SourceRow, SourceColumn).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))
        SourceColumn = SourceColumn + 1
    Next rcell
End Sub

'The main routine where we define where data goes and comes from
Sub DataEntry()
    Dim dataWS As Worksheet, Path1 As String, WsName1 As String

    Dim testFileName As Range, file

    Dim avgDmmV As Range, avgPSTATADCV As Range, ppPSTATADCV As Range

    Dim gainLO0A As Range, gainLO0B As Range, gainLOm10A As Range, gainLOm10B As Range
    Dim gainLO10A As Range, gainLO10B As Range, gainLO20A As Range, gainLO20B As Range
    Dim gainLO60A As Range, gainLO60B As Range

    Set dataWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
    Path1 = "\\server5\Operations\MainBoard testing central location DO NOT REMOVE or RENAME" 'File path Location
    WsName1 = "Summary"

    'The values of the cells in this range have the names of the .xls files
    Set testFileName = dataWS.Range("A6", dataWS.Range("A6").End(xlDown)) 

    For Each file In testFileName 'Loop through each file name
        dataRow = file.Row

        Set avgDmmV = dataWS.Range("C" & dataRow & ":F" & dataRow)
        Set avgPSTATADCV = dataWS.Range("H" & dataRow & ":M" & dataRow)
        Set ppPSTATADCV = dataWS.Range("Q" & dataRow & ":W" & dataRow)

        Set gainLO0A = dataWS.Range("Y" & dataRow & ":AG" & dataRow)
        Set gainLO0B = dataWS.Range("AI" & dataRow & ":AQ" & dataRow)
        Set gainLOm10A = dataWS.Range("AS" & dataRow & ":BA" & dataRow)
        Set gainLOm10B = dataWS.Range("BC" & dataRow & ":BK" & dataRow)
        Set gainLO10A = dataWS.Range("BM" & dataRow & ":BU" & dataRow)
        Set gainLO10B = dataWS.Range("BW" & dataRow & ":CE" & dataRow)
        Set gainLO20A = dataWS.Range("CG" & dataRow & ":CO" & dataRow)
        Set gainLO20B = dataWS.Range("CQ" & dataRow & ":CY" & dataRow)
        Set gainLO60A = dataWS.Range("DA" & dataRow & ":DI" & dataRow)
        Set gainLO60B = dataWS.Range("DK" & dataRow & ":DS" & dataRow)

        Call DataLoop(avgDmmV, 9, 5, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)
        Call DataLoop(avgPSTATADCV, 15, 5, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)
        Call DataLoop(ppPSTATADCV, 18, 5, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)

        Call DataLoop(gainLO0A, 31, 3, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)
        Call DataLoop(gainLO0B, 32, 3, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)
        Call DataLoop(gainLOm10A, 33, 3, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)
        Call DataLoop(gainLOm10B, 34, 3, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)
        Call DataLoop(gainLO10A, 35, 3, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)
        Call DataLoop(gainLO10B, 36, 3, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)
        Call DataLoop(gainLO20A, 37, 3, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)
        Call DataLoop(gainLO20B, 38, 3, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)
        Call DataLoop(gainLO60A, 39, 3, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)
        Call DataLoop(gainLO60B, 40, 3, Path1, CStr(file.Value), WsName1)
    Next file
End Sub
```

Comment: Just curious - is it usual, or recommended, to close the activeworkbook when running a function? Something about that sounds like it may not be recommended...but I guess it's really no different than closing a workbook in a `Sub`.... hm.

Comment: @BruceWayne No, I've never done it before. It doesn't seem like good programming practice to try and do something like that.

Comment: Thank you Tyler, this works exactly like my current code, your help is appreciated.

Comment: @Allan if you're satisfied with this as the answer, could you mark it as such?

Comment: @Allan - Take note of removing the workbook closing from the function.  It's really not a good idea to put a close even in a function - if you open the workbook again, and change the value of any cell, that UDF (your custom function) is likely to recalculate, which means run through and close the workbook...I don't think you want it doing that *each time* a calculation is done or cell is changed.

Comment: @BruceWayne I updated my answer to discourage performing this the original way that Allan had it (to discourage future viewers from doing the same, nothing against you Allan :))

Comment: @BruceWayne I agree, closing and opening a WB 500 times means trouble. would it be possible to assign a cell to open the file and an other cell to close ?  (A1 Open wb Z1 close wb)

Comment: @Allan use the code in this answer. You don't have to `Call closeWB(Path)` until you're done with the workbook. If you are going to have multiple open at a time, just make `Path` an array, and cycle through it with the `closeWB` sub and a For loop. Ezpz

Comment: @Tyeler, I added an applied example to your code, it his what you intended the code to be applied like?

Comment: @Allan Yes, something like that. You should find that it fits your needs more intuitivly and it's much more flexible this way.

Comment: @Tyler, it is more Intuitive, but I still get the same results, workbooksremains open. am I calling it correctly? on each cell of the destination workbook added `=getfield("\\server\Operations\Testing central location\"&$A6,"Summary","E9")` Thanks!

Comment: @Tyeler This outputs #VALUE! :-(

Comment: @Allan I see what your problem is, gimme a sec, I'm updating the answer.

Comment: @Tyeler, Thank you so much for helping out, I had been suffering all weak with this issue. But finally, You have shined light in my obscure path of Excel pain. I was about to get a chicken and a goat and offer them to the gods, but I guess I can spare them for an other occasion. Thanks again!

Comment: @Allan Did you get it to work? I think the best solution for getting the workbooks to close might be by putting the closeWB call in the `Workbook_SheetChange` sub.. but depending on what you're doing, that is a very very INFLEXIBLE way of dealing with it. I now see why you were trying to put the .Close event in your function.

Comment: @Tyeler noup it is not closing any books

Comment: @Tyeler The updated Answer WORKS AWESOME! you just sit and look at the wb populate by it self, thousands of cells! it looks like too much information but not if you know what you are looking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well how about querying the excel files using ADO instead?

```
Function getField(Path As String, WorksheetName As String, CellRange As String) As Variant
    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & Path & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;"";"

    objRecordset.Open "Select F" & Range(CellRange).Column & " as Val  FROM [" & WorksheetName & "$]", _
        objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

    objRecordset.Move Range(CellRange).Row - 1

    getField = objRecordset("Val")

    objRecordset.Close
    objConnection.Close
End Function
```