# Password protect without unprotecting

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that will distributed to multiple departments. Each department has their own sheet within the workbook, they will have to input notes in certain cells. I've password protected each sheet except for the cells where they'll be inputting their notes (lots of formulas referencing other sheets, can't be touched by anyone except for me). On top of the password protection, I added a VBA code to that immediately prompts the user for a password before they can add notes (to discourage other departments from inputting notes into the wrong sheet.) Each department has their own password for their sheet. The problem is, my code unprotects the entire sheet when the correct departmental password is entered, exposing my locked cells to the other users. I need a code that will prompt the user when the sheet is selected, and when the password is enetered correctly, it will only unprotect the unlocked cells. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Const Passwrd As String = "abc123"
    Dim sInput As Variant
    Dim Attempt As Integer
    Me.Protect Password:=Passwrd
    Attempt = 1
    Do
    sInput = InputBox("Please enter the password for this sheet", "Password    Required    Attempt:" & Attempt)
        If StrPtr(sInput) = 0 Then
        'cancel pressed
            Exit Do
        ElseIf sInput = Passwrd Then    ' Valid Password
            Me.Unprotect Password:=Passwrd
            Exit Do
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid Password", 48, "Invalid"
            Attempt = Attempt + 1
        End If
    Loop Until Attempt > 3    ' "Don't let the inputbox close if the password is not correct

End Sub
```

Comment: Set up a range of cells that can be edited per sheet (named would be best), and then just toggle the `.Locked` property instead of leaving the sheet unprotected.

Comment: In a similar situation, I have left the worksheet protected, but with defined ranges available for each department that will be editing it.  I track the user who has opened the spreadsheet and map them to their department.  Then use the worksheet_open event to `.locked = True` or `.locked = False` the various ranges for the relevant department and they can only edit their own "area"

Comment: I had a similar situation; since everyone may use the archive as they please, I used the approach of having a master file where all the singles ones are collected. In the master file, I have the protection for the matter.

Comment: Why does this all have to be in the same workbook? Can you make this server based? Or database style? What I'm getting at is, can you let each department have their own workbook, and you have your own, then just fetch the information via vba to your workbook as you need it? This would get rid of the need for passwords, you could also send whatever pertinent information from other departments as needed, and data would never get mixed up.

Comment: Great idea Tyeler!

Comment: If you want some code excerpts that relate to pulling data out of other closed workbooks (or open) from a different computer on the same network, give [my answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535789/vba-close-workbook-after-acquiring-necessary-information/39536483#39536483) a look. Specifically the code at the bottom of the answer, after the bold paragraph. It might spark a new idea for you.