# How to read selected number of cell from another excel without opening it using VBA

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

```
Dim xlsPath As String
xlsPath = "C:\"
Workbooks(xlsPath & "Output.xls").Sheets("Output").Range("B2:B6").Copy
```

I am trying above code for this but getting error.

Comment: What error do you get?  You cannot copy from a closed workbook.  Why not open it?

Comment: error is Subscript out of range. I am automating a process so I dont want to open a excel during that process.

Comment: you can make open it and make it invisible to users

Comment: Probably that sheet "Output" does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference the Workbook xlsPath & "Output.xls", it needs to already be opened in Excel. This is explained in the Workbook Object definition [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224504%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

> ... the workbook must already be open in Microsoft Excel.

What you probably want to do is use the ExecuteExcel4Macro function as was previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259862/executeexcel4macro-to-get-value-from-closed-workbook).

Comment: Resolved -- I tried below code to access data without opening another excel.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Output.xls"
Workbooks("Input.xls").Worksheets("abc").Activate
..............
..............
Workbooks("Output.xls").Close SaveChanges:=False

Comment: Ok, I answered based on your question - how to do this without opening it. You obviously just meant you didn't want to see it when it was opened. Good job figuring that out.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved -- I tried below code to access data without opening another excel.

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Output.xls" 
Workbooks("Input.xls").Worksheets("abc").Activate

Workbooks("Output.xls").Close SaveChanges:=False`