# GetValue + loop = Can it go faster?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created main file which imports data from other (closed) excel files. There is x-ten of files from which I need to import data. I made a code in UserForm so that mine boss can choose where to import (sheet = wariant) file. It is not completed because I need to add options button (for choosing which file to import), but main core will look like beneath.

But there is a problem, in our company we have a medium class laptops, so that code (beneath) in executin in 5-7 minutes for each file (wariant). I need it to run as fast as possible. Can you make something with it?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

StartTime = Timer

Dim p As String
Dim f As String
Dim s As String
Dim a As String
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim Warinat As String

    If UserForm1.War1 = True Then Wariant = "Wariant 1"
    If UserForm1.War2 = True Then Wariant = "Wariant 2"
    If UserForm1.War3 = True Then Wariant = "Wariant 3"
    If UserForm1.War4 = True Then Wariant = "Wariant 4"

    p = ThisWorkbook.path
    f = "files.xlsx"
    s = "Sheet1"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For r = 7 To 137
    For c = 2 To 96
    a = Cells(r, c).Address
    If IsNumeric(Cells(r, c)) = True And ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Wariant).Cells(r, c) <> "" _
    Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Wariant).Cells(r, c) = _ 
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Wariant).Cells(r, c).Value + GetValue(p, f, s, a)
     Else
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Wariant).Cells(r, c) = GetValue(p, f, s, a)
     End If
     Next c
    Next r

EndTime = Timer
MsgBox Format(EndTime - StartTime, ssss)

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)

    Dim arg As String

    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "Files is missing"
        Exit Function
    End If

    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _ 
Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)

GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)

End Function

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim Warinat As String` has a typo. Use `Option Explicit` as the first line of the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ExecuteExcel4Macro call is likely slowing down the process, as it opens the same workbook 12,445 times. You're dealing with two 2-D arrays; one in your Wariant sheet and one in your imported workbook. Try something like this.

```
Dim var1 As Variant
Dim var2 As Variant
Dim wbImport As Workbook

'Set var1 as your range value
var1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Wariant).Range("B7:CR137").Value

'Open the Import workbook, set the value, then close it.
Set wbImport = Application.Workbooks.Open(p & f)
var2 = wbImport.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7:CR137").Value
wbImport.Close

'Now loop through the variant arrays - much faster
For r = 1 To 131
    For c = 1 To 95

        If IsNumeric(var1(r, c)) And var1(r, c) <> "" Then
            var1(r, c) = _
            var1(r, c) + var2(r, c)
        Else
            var1(r, c) = var2(r, c)
        End If
    Next c
Next r

'Finally, copy the variant array back into the workbook.
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Wariant).Range("B7:CR137").Value = var1
```

Comment: I regard this as the definitive answer: reading the range into an array a single 'hit' is always faster than multiple reads of individual cells: so much so that you may as well regard anything you do in VBA to the array as taking zero time... Except if it's something **really** slow, like opening files, or reading from closed files. Or, as Stadem has pointed out, reading the same workbook thousands of times. Open the file, and keep it open, and maybe look at a way of grabbing that data into an array in a single 'hit', too!

Comment: Thank you, it really works under 2 seconds :) I am a beginner in VBA so I will learn a lot from your code!

Answer (score 1):

It will probably run faster if you open each workbook rather than reading cell-by-cell from a closed workbook.

Answer (score 0):

not without knowing what you are calling with ExecuteExcel4Macro function, because called macro can be anything and very likely is reason why your code excecutes slowly

```
GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, but I guess ExecuteExcel4Macro is actually a standard VBA function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193589.aspx

Comment: yeah, standard function that starts custom macro

Comment: In @BenNowak's case, the argument doesn't call a macro; it calls a cell reference value. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27527560/5103770

Answer (score 0):

To do this without opening the workbook you can paste this code into a new module:

```
Dim v As Variant

Function GetValues(p As String, f As String, s As String, a As String)
v = Empty
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!SetV('" & p & "\[" & f & "]" & s & "'!" & a & ")"
GetValues = v
End Function

Public Function SetV(Value)
v = Value
End Function
```

You can then retrieve all the values from the closed workbook in a single call like this:

```
GetValues(ThisWorkbook.path,"files.xlsx","Sheet1","r7c2:r137c96")
```