# Vba reference workbook via Path

Tags: vba, excel

I am making a Macro is Excel 2016 and want to reference a workbook via it's path without opening it.

This is what I have done at the moment

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Path As String
Dim Fd As FileDialog

Set Fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
Fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
Fd.Show

Path = Fd.SelectedItems(1)

Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Path)
```

However, the last line opens up the file.

I'd like to know the way to set Wb as the workbook where the path leads to without opening it.

Comment: You can't. `WB` is a Workbook *object*.  Besides, you've *already* gotten a reference to the path itself, via the `Path` variable. Perhaps if you can describe more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can't I store a workbook object in `Wb` which is the workbook the path leads to? I just need to reference that workbook so that I can retrieve some data from its cells later on. @DavidZemens

Comment: No, it just doesn't work that way because a `Workbook` must be *open* in order to be a workbook!  You can retrieve data from closed Workbooks, though, if that's what you're after. Or, you can open them invisibly in a separate instance of Excel, and retrieve data that way.

Comment: Ah I see then. It's not really a big problem if the workbook opens but it'd look better if it didn't. Thank you for your help @DavidZemens.

Comment: The simplest way to do that is to just open it invisibly in a new instance of Excel. I will post simple code for that in a moment.

Comment: I agree with @DavidZemens. And if you want to retrieve values from a closed workbook then see [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259862/executeexcel4macro-to-get-value-from-closed-workbook)

Answer (score 2):

> I just need to reference that workbook so that I can retrieve some data from its cells later on. Can't I store a workbook object in Wb which is the workbook the path leads to?

Nope. Until a file is open in Excel, it isn't a workbook, even though you & I might *think* of it *as* a workbook, it's not. It's just a file. But you can get data from closed workbooks.

There are a few ways that this is commonly done (there may be others):

1. For small amounts of data, use `ExecuteExcel4Macro` method.
2. For large amounts of data, use `ADO` to query the workbook.
3. For simple solution, just open the file and keep it invisible.

I'll cover the simplest way to do that, which is to just open it invisibly in a new instance of Excel. This is only slightly more complicated than opening it *visibly* in the same instance of Excel. You'll just need to create a new Excel instance, set its `.Visible` property to `False`, and open the file in *that* instance.

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim xlApp as Excel.Application 
Dim Path As String
Dim Fd As FileDialog

Set Fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
Fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
Fd.Show

If Fd.SelectedItems > 0 Then
    Path = Fd.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing selected!"
    Exit Sub
End If

'## Create new instance of excel, and make it invisible
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = False
'## Open your workbook in this new instance
'   I use ReadOnly:=True to prevent conflict if the file is already open elsewhere
Set Wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path, ReadOnly:=True)
```

Make sure that at the end of your procedure you do this, to close the workbook and quit the new/invisible Excel instance:

```
Wb.Close 
xlApp.Quit
```

Comment: I will try it out. Thank you so much