# excel: if FileExists, if a given value is x in the file, then pull the data from a given cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a function which checks if a file exists, if the file exists then it checks for a specific value in a specific cell, if thats true then it pulls the value from a given cell.

Problem is, a dialouge box keeps appearing when I run this code. I have inserted

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

into my FileExists function but I still get the dialogue box, any idea what Im doing wrong?

my function:

```
Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Step 1: Declare your variables.
    Dim FileName As String

'Step 2: Use the Dir function to get the file name
    FileName = Dir(FilePath)

'Step 3:  If file exists, return True else False
    If FileName <> "" Then FileExists = True _
    Else: FileExists = False

End Function

Sub FileExits()

End Sub
```

What Im inserting to the formula box:

```
=IF(FileExists("path\filename.xls"),IF('path\[filename.xls]Sheet'!D$13="16m8", 'path\[filename.xls]Sheet'!D40, ""),"false")
```

continued from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452159/excel-pull-data-from-one-excel-file-to-another-if-the-file-exists

Comment: What dialog box are you getting?

Comment: directory/path to file. But the file exists, so Im not sure why it throws that up.

Comment: that sucks! so I have to retrieve the values via vba macro? or is there another solution?

Comment: If the file exists, check the spelling of the sheet name, is it really just `"Sheet"`, or should it be `"Sheet1"` (or something else)?

Comment: Also see my suggestion below, I think this would be a better solution anyways. The formula is a bit easier to write & comprehend, and it makes use of Excel built-in function for retrieving value from closed workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was slightly mistaken in my comment on the OP. Yes, you can retrieve values this way (kind of) but the dialog you're seeing is what happens if the file doesn't exist, because Excel's boolean logic doesn't short circuit.

What this means is that if the named file doesn't exist, Excel still has to evaluate the full expression, and it *can't* evaluate this part if the named file doesn't exist.

```
IF('path\[filename.xls]Sheet'!D$13="16m8", 'path\[filename.xls]Sheet'!D40, "")
```

As @pnuts mentions above, when `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`,

> [Excel] will resort to default options where these exist (eg without saving for Close) but there is no default option for 'I can't find the file you told me to use'

**NOTE** If the named file does exist, you might still get the dialog box if the specified Sheet names don't exist.

## Alternative solution:

Since you're already using a custom function `FileExists`, just use something like this (modified slightly from Sid's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259862/executeexcel4macro-to-get-value-from-closed-workbook)) to get values from closed workbooks:

```
Function GetVal(path$, shtName$, cellRef$)

Dim exists As Boolean, ret
Dim fileName$, directory$, sht$, addr$

    exists = Dir(Trim(path)) <> vbNullString

    If Not exists Then GoTo EarlyExit

    'Else, if the file exists, get the values
    path = Replace(path, "/", "\")
    'Get the query substrings:
    fileName = Dir(path)
    directory = Left$(path, Len(path) - Len(fileName))

    'Get the address of the cell, R1C1 style
    addr = Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)
    'Build the query string in the ExecuteExcel4Macro function
    ret = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & directory & "[" & fileName & "]" & shtName & "'!" & addr)

    GetVal = ret

EarlyExit:
    ret = "File or sheetname doesn't exist!"  '## Modify as needed
End Function
```

Then, modify your logic, so that instead of:

```
=IF(FileExists("path\filename.xls"),IF('path\[filename.xls]Sheet'!D$13="16m8", 'path\[filename.xls]Sheet'!D40, ""),"false")
```

You do this:

```
=IF(GetVal("path\filename.xls", "Sheet1", "D$13")="16m8", GetVal("path\filename.xls", "Sheet1", "D40"))
```

The above function uses same logic as your `FileExists`, and does ensure the file exists before handing the query to `ExecuteExcel4Macro` built-in function.