# Link to external workbook based on another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm working on dynamic external workbook data referencing in Excel, can someone please help considering the following:

In my workbook in A2 I have
 =`'C:\'&A1&' Reports\[1.xls]Sheet1'!C1)`

`A1` will contain either

> Folder A
>   Folder B

So depending on the value in A1, I want to point to either

> D:\Folder A Reports\1.xls
>   D:\Folder B Reports\1.xls

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: You could use an IF statement or a VLOOKUP table. This of course assumes you just need to return a value dependent on a lookup value.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was just hoping to have Folder A populate in the path for A2, like calling a variable. Is it not possible to do it this way?

Comment: It is certainly possible, but I apologize as I am not completely sure what you are trying to accomplish. You can certainly have the path populate based on the value of A1, and there are a few ways of accomplishing this. As I noted, a vlookup is one way of doing this. I am getting the feeling though that you want a formula to find the path on it's own without you providing it in a table? This is possible as well, but this will enter the realm of VBA and not just excel formulas.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259862/executeexcel4macro-to-get-value-from-closed-workbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indirect is the function you need:

```
=INDIRECT("'C:\" & A1 & " Reports\[1.xls]Sheet1'!C1")
```

The problem I see though is it won't resolve if the sheet is not open.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I hard code the path, I can simply open the workbook and close it,and the data will update... So I've written a macro that will open all the spreadsheets I need and close them... For the INDIRECT function, must the spreadsheets remain open, or can I use the same macro to open and close my external sources?

Comment: Open it, refresh it, close it and it will remain with the answer. I have to ask though, why wouldn't you just copy the data from the sheet with code and put it into your target sheet as a value with no dependency at runtime?

Comment: It's too much to do manually. A lot of tabs and sources... Can't wait to go home and try it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As `INDIRECT` doesn't work on closed books and it is expensive to have to open them then the normal soutions for this are to

1. create a *dirty* link with VBA.
2. Use `Indirect.Ext` from  the *Morefunc* addin.
3. My preferred approach, use `XLM` which Harlan Grove has improved in his *pull* function below.

To use for your purpose:

`=pull("'C:\"&A1&"\"&"[1.xls]Sheet1'!C1")`

From https://numbermonger.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/excel-pull-function-creating-dynamic-links-to-closed-workbooks/

*Pull function*

```
Function pull(xref As String) As Variant
'inspired by Bob Phillips and Laurent Longre
'but written by Harlan Grove
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
'Copyright (c) 2003 Harlan Grove.
'
'This code is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
'it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published
'by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License,
'or (at your option) any later version.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
'2004-05-30
'still more fixes, this time to address apparent differences between
'XL8/97 and later versions. Specifically, fixed the InStrRev call,
'which is fubar in later versions and was using my own hacked version
'under XL8/97 which was using the wrong argument syntax. Also either
'XL8/97 didn't choke on CStr(pull) called when pull referred to an
'array while later versions do, or I never tested the 2004-03-25 fix
'against multiple cell references.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------

'2004-05-28
'fixed the previous fix - replaced all instances of 'expr' with 'xref'
'also now checking for initial single quote in xref, and if found
'advancing past it to get the full pathname [dumb, really dumb!]
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
'2004-03-25
'revised to check if filename in xref exists - if it does, proceed;
'otherwise, return a #REF! error immediately - this avoids Excel
'displaying dialogs when the referenced file doesn't exist
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
Dim xlapp As Object, xlwb As Workbook
Dim b As String, r As Range, C As Range, n As Long
'** begin 2004-05-30 changes **

'** begin 2004-05-28 changes **
'** begin 2004-03-25 changes **
n = InStrRev(xref, "\")
If n > 0 Then
If Mid(xref, n, 2) = "\[" Then
b = Left(xref, n)
n = InStr(n + 2, xref, "]") - n - 2
If n > 0 Then b = b & Mid(xref, Len(b) + 2, n)
Else
n = InStrRev(Len(xref), xref, "!")
If n > 0 Then b = Left(xref, n - 1)
End If

'** key 2004-05-28 addition **
If Left(b, 1) = "'" Then b = Mid(b, 2)
On Error Resume Next
If n > 0 Then If Dir(b) = "" Then n = 0
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
End If

If n <= 0 Then
pull = CVErr(xlErrRef)
Exit Function
End If
'** end 2004-03-25 changes **
'** end 2004-05-28 changes **
pull = Evaluate(xref)

'** key 2004-05-30 addition **
If IsArray(pull) Then Exit Function
'** end 2004-05-30 changes **

If CStr(pull) = CStr(CVErr(xlErrRef)) Then
On Error GoTo CleanUp 'immediate clean-up at this point

Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Add 'needed by .ExecuteExcel4Macro

On Error Resume Next 'now clean-up can wait

n = InStr(InStr(1, xref, "]") + 1, xref, "!")
b = Mid(xref, 1, n)

Set r = xlwb.Sheets(1).Range(Mid(xref, n + 1))

If r Is Nothing Then
pull = xlapp.ExecuteExcel4Macro(xref)

Else
For Each C In r
C.Value = xlapp.ExecuteExcel4Macro(b & C.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1))
Next C

pull = r.Value

End If

CleanUp:
If Not xlwb Is Nothing Then xlwb.Close 0
If Not xlapp Is Nothing Then xlapp.Quit
Set xlapp = Nothing

End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

External references to closed files in Excel formulas can't be dynamic, so maybe something like this:

```
=IF(A1="Folder A", 'C:\Folder A Reports\[1.xls]Sheet1'!C1,
                   'C:\Folder B Reports\[1.xls]Sheet1'!C1)
```