# Using Workbook.Sheets.Range to reference file path in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

First, is what I'm doing here logical?
Second, I keep getting an error on my single quote that begins my filepath.

```
stuff = Workbooks('\\public\Documents\Amazon Retail\Analysis\[US Retail Quick Reference.xlsx]').Sheets("Quick Reference").Range("A1")
```

Comment: 1) change `'` to `"` (but then you may need a double backslash?:  `"\\public...`) 2) if `stuff` is to reference a `Range` then use a `Set` keyword before `stuff`

Comment: Done, but it still gives me a "Subscript out of range" which means It can't find my file (the file path is 100% accurate).

Comment: What is the error that you're receiving? Including it in your answer helps everyone...

Comment: one thing only is really _"100% accurate"_ in human life; but that is too sad to remember ... double check the path! (may be with a `Dir()`).

Comment: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. Checked the file path a dozen times.

Comment: What is your _current_ code?

Comment: Rum-time error 9 is my current code

Comment: strange code...

Comment: If that file is already open, you have to reference it by its *name* only, not the full path. If the file isn't yet open, you need to open it first (and then refer to it by its name only).

Comment: show a relevant piece of code reproducing the error

Comment: The file isn't local. Is there a way to reference a non-local file path?

Comment: **You can't use *`Workbooks`* to refer to a file that isn't already open**.  (*`Workbooks Object (Excel)`*: A collection of all the Workbook objects that are *currently open* in the Microsoft Excel application.) ...when referring to a file is **is** open, you shouldn't use the path (as you'll get an error.)

Comment: @DavidZemens showed you the right path, valid for local and not local files

Comment: what do you mean by a "foreign file"?

Comment: You cannot have two files with the same *Name* open in a single instance of Excel. This is only possible if you're using multiple instances of Excel, in which case the problem becomes more difficult because you need to identify which instance (of however many) may have the file open, and that's far more complicated using `WinAPI` calls like `FindWindow` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a single instance of Excel, and are not using multiple instances of Excel:

If that file is already open, you have to reference it by its *name* only, not the full path. If the file isn't yet open, you need to open it first (and then refer to it by its name only).

Change this:

```
stuff = Workbooks('\\public\Documents\Amazon Retail\Analysis\[US Retail Quick Reference.xlsx]').Sheets("Quick Reference").Range("A1")
```

To This:

```
stuff = Workbooks("US Retail Quick Reference.xlsx").Sheets("Quick Reference").Range("A1")
```

Ensure `stuff` is declared as a `String` or possibly as a `Variant` type (in case A1 might contain non-text or error values).

If you don't know at runtime whether the file is or may be open, then you can fancify your code like so:

```
Function IsWorkbookOpen(path as String, name as String) As Boolean
    Dim wb as Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks(name)
    If wb.FullName = path & name Then
        IsWorkbookOpen = True
    End If
End Function
```

And then do like:

```
Dim path as String, fileName as String
path = "\\public\Documents\Amazon Retail\Analysis\"
fileName = "US Retail Quick Reference.xlsx"
If (IsWorkbookOpen(path & fileName)) Then
    stuff = Workbooks(fileName).Sheets("Quick Reference").Range("A1").Value
Else
    ' Do Something Else // UNTESTED:
    stuff = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & path & "[" & fileName & "]" & _
          "Quick Reference'!" & Range("A1").Address(True, True, -4150))

    ' or:
    ' Dim wb as Workbook
    ' Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path + fileName)
    ' stuff = wb.Sheets("Quick Reference").Range("A1").Value
    ' wb.Close

End If
```

For the "Something Else", I'd recommend using the [`ExecuteExcel4Macro` method for obtaining value from a closed workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259862/executeexcel4macro-to-get-value-from-closed-workbook).