# Run-time error '1004' when I'm referring to a range that is not named

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, worksheet

I'm trying to put a dropdown menu in an Excel worksheet, with options from another worksheet, in another workbook. I'm using VBA because **I want to customize those options, based on another dropdown menu**. I managed to do it by naming the range in the source sheet, but that file is read-only so I can't save the name to automate the process. So I tried to use only the column name in the reference (like $B:$B, I only need the B column), but when I run the macro it stops with Run-time error 1004.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("H6")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call main
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub main()
    reason = Range("H6").Value
    List = ""

    If reason = "Project ID/Task ID" Then
        List = "=PIDTID"
    Else
        List = "=Cost_Center"
    End If

    With Range("I6").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=List
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

This is my macro, as you can see, `main()` is called when H6 is changed, because that is where my other dropdown menu is. Then, based on the value from that cell, List gets assigned a value equal to the defined name that refers to the range in the other worksheet.

As an example, if PIDTID name is equal to `='[20190812_WP_and_CostCenters_Responsible.xls]Projects responsibles'!WBSName`, the script works. Note that WBSName is the name given to column B in the source sheet.

If I set PIDTID to `='[20190812_WP_and_CostCenters_Responsible.xls]Projects responsibles'!$B:$B` I will get the error on line

`.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=List`

`Cost_Center` name acts the same.

I want to mention that these tests were done having the source file opened. If I tried with it being closed, I would get the same error.

Is there a way to get rid of the error, or another way by which I can refer to cells in sheets of other workbooks without naming them? I would also like to work without having to open the source file. Thank you!

Comment: The error itself is quite logical as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/external-references-data-validation-fails) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Is there a way to get rid of the error, or another way by which I can refer to cells in sheets of other workbooks without naming them? I would also like to work without having to open the source file. Thank you!"*

Let me give it a go :)

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/external-references-data-validation-fails) documentation, you cannot use referces to another workbook (without a named range). And certainly not in a closed workbook. Refer to @Gh3ttoKinG his answer for that :).

So this might be done much smarter but to do this **without opening** a workbook I thought about using `ExecuteExcel4Macro`. With a little help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9261915/9758194) answer by @SiddharthRout, we can start pulling in information from the closed workbook:

```
Sub Test()

Dim wbPath As String, wbName As String
Dim wsName As String, cellRef As String
Dim Ret As String
Dim lr As Long
Dim arr() As String

wbPath = "C:\Users\....\SO\"
wbName = "SO.xlsx"
wsName = "Sheet1"

'Get the last row from B column, notice we need R1C1 notation for Excel4Macro
lr = ExecuteExcel4Macro("COUNTA('" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!C2)")

'Let's use an array to fill our validation list with later on
ReDim arr(1 To lr)
For x = 1 To lr
    arr(x) = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!R" & x & "C2")
Next x

'Join the array together to make a string which will be accepted in the validation list
With Range("I6").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Join(arr, ",")
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

End Sub
```

There are some things I would try to "smoothen" as for example `COUNTA` is not the best to get the `lr` variable, plus there might be a way to pull a complete range into the `arr()` variable at once.

However, this might spark some creative ideas ;)

---

**EDIT**

Another way to retrieve the last row on string data could be to use `MATCH` like so:

```
lr = ExecuteExcel4Macro("MATCH(""zzz"",'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!C2)")
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it was very helpful, and it even helps me further, with some issues I had no idea how get around. However, I'm experiencing a new problem I didn's have at first: `COUNTA` returns the value 983237 unless the file I'm reading is opened. Do you have any idea why does that happen?

Comment: @VladIordache, I included another option, which might work for you? If that doesn't help, you might have values in your column actually. Maybe even spaces or formula output being ""?

Comment: Thank you sir, it works perfectly now. I did not have values, because the output was correct when the file was opened. The behaviour was the same for `COUNTA`, `COUNTIF`, `SUMPRODUCT`, even the difference between `ROWS` and `COUNTBLANK`. But your solution with `MATCH` was exactly what I needed, thank you again. However, I would still like to know what's with that strange number

Answer (score 1):

As JvdV wrote in the comments it's because you can't use data validation where the list reference to another workbook, at least not in a simple way.

[image: external reference in Data Validation not possible]

You can circument it by adding a named range to your writeable workbook with this formula (assuming `Cost_Center` is in column C)

```
=IF(Sheet1!H6="PIDTID",OFFSET('[20190812_WP_and_CostCenters_Responsible.xls]Projects responsibles'!$B:$B,0,0),OFFSET('[20190812_WP_and_CostCenters_Responsible.xls]Projects responsibles'!$C:$C,0,0))
```

And then use this named range in your data validation / macro.
Downside is that the source workbook has to open for the dropdown menu to work