# External reference from a TEXT STRING

Tags: excel, text, reference, eval, excel-indirect

I want to create an external reference to a closed workbook from a **text string**. This question is different from "Referencing value in a closed Excel workbook using INDIRECT?" as I need to generate a text string first. The purpose is that  I can write a file name in a cell and get the content from a range of cells from a certain sheet of that workbook.
I added the Eval function in VBA. It works fine while the workbook is open, also with the entire file path, but it fails as soon as I close it. The same happens using the INDEX or INDIRECT function. This is only when I use a text string, using the external reference or INDEX directly it works. What am I missing?

When workbook is open:
`=[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1`              works;
`[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1`together with`=Eval(C3)` works;
generating a text string from two cells containing `[Book1.xlsx]`   `Sheet1!$A$1` by `=A5&B5` followed by `=Eval(C5)`   works as well.

When workbook is closed: `='E:\Excel\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1` works but `E:\Excel\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1` with `=Eval("'"&I3)` or `=INDIRECT("'"&I3)`fails. Then I open Book1 and voila! it works again, so the file path is correct, right? Is there a specific character I am missing?

[Open workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFOvW.png)
[Closed workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IM3N.png)

Comment: "*What am I missing?*" You can't do this with INDIRECT or INDEX. As the linked thread says, "there is definitively no way to do this with standard formulas." Reconsider your approach.

Comment: OK, got it, thanks. Any links to non-standard approaches? I can't find any hint that anyone solved this issue by any means.

Comment: I've never tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259862/executeexcel4macro-to-get-value-from-closed-workbook). Maybe worth researching or trying. It does rely on quite old Excel functionality.